# Confusion with posix threads in cpp

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I'm really confused with this particular code. AFAIK, this program should not have a race condition but it does. What is really confusing is removing the loops and just duplicating the code works fine.

NOTE: I saw a question about threads in a loop but it does not really capture what i'm trying to impose.

Here it is

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>

void *functionC(void*);
pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int counter = 0;


int main() {
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    pthread_t threads[] = { thread1, thread2 };

    for (auto th : threads) {
        if (pthread_create(&th, NULL, &functionC, NULL) != 0)
        {
            printf("Thread Creation Failed");
        }
    }

    for (auto th : threads) {
        pthread_join(th, NULL);
    }

    exit(0);
}

void *functionC(void *) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);

    counter++;
    printf("Counter Value: %d\n", counter);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

    return NULL;
}
```

Built as follows

```
FILE=mutex

all:
        g++ $(FILE).cpp -lpthread -o bin && ./bin
```

I was expecting the counter variable to increment once per thread but sometimes nothing prints other times the counter variable remains 1 for both executions which i have read is due to low level scheduling operations.

Comment: What OS are you running on?  What specific compiler version are you using?

Comment: Since the question is tagged with c++ : any reason not to use `std::thread`, `std::mutex` ?

Comment: This isn't the cause of your problem today, but don't use pthreads in a C++ program. It might work for you now, but there's no guarantee that it will continue to work for you in the future. Use `std::thread`. It's part of the language. Pthreads is _not_ part of the language. Using pthreads is like having an after-market air conditioner installed in your car. (That used to be an actual thing when I was a kid, and they never worked as reliably as a factory-installed one.)

Comment: In addition to what Solomon said, if you have a **pthread** based platform, the `std::thread` will be implemented in terms of pthread.  No need to use them directly; use the C++ abstraction (which also will provide well defined behavior, whereas directly using pthread may not provide well defined behavior; and will be portable to other thread-supporting non-pthread platforms).

Answer (score 4):

Your bug is here (two places, the first of which is critical):

```
for (auto th : threads) {
```

That should be:

```
for (auto& th : threads) {
```

It needs to be a reference so that when you take the address of `th` and pass it to `pthread_create()`, you are actually passing the address of `threads[0]` and not merely the address of `th`.

Also note that `thread1` and `thread2` are useless in your program, and should be removed.  Enabling compiler warnings would tell you this.

Comment: Since the OP claims there is a race condition, it should be noted that the only race condition here is between the program's initial thread terminating and the others terminating.  And this because the `pthread_join()` calls are (presumably) not passing the correct thread IDs.  It should also be noted that the OP could have been clued in to the nature of the error if they checked the return values of their function calls, especially the `pthread_join()` calls.

Comment: Appreciate the responses, but I think the answer that best resonates with my problem is the one from @JohnBollinger since I really was focused on  the race condition. I would appreciate it if the program was actually run by someone since the return values of pthread_join calls are both "3", and the program does not behave as expected at all.

Comment: I also used cpp just for the easy loops. It's a bit lazy though. But shouldn't cpp work with pthreads since cpp is supposed to be "compatible" with c

Comment: @DaVinci, who says C++ is compatible with C?  The two share a common subset that is large enough to program in, but they are distinct languages.  There is valid C code that is not valid C++ code and *vice versa*, and there is code that is valid in both languages but means different things in one and the other.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks again for the response but I'm aware that C++ is not entirely compatible with C, I thought I made that clear when I said "compatible" instead of compatible. Thanks again though